# Can Fiddler's HTTP packet tampering be replicated with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, http, fiddler

I want to capture particular HTTP requests from a Flash game and then alter the HTTP responses it receives. I can currently do this using Fiddler, but I want to write some Javascript that achieves the same programmatically. Is it possible to capture and alter HTTP browser traffic with JS like this?

Regarding my motivations, I am part of a community who enjoy playing an ancient Flash game. Part of the game involves uploading your own levels to the game's server. Unfortunately, this is broken - when you request the level from the server via the game, the server always reports failure, presumably due to no longer being maintained. So, in order to play our levels, we are using Fiddler to capture the game's HTTP requests that ask the server for the level data and then altering the server failure response by inserting our level data. I am trying to automate this process on a webpage.

Is HTTP packet sniffing feasible in Javascript? Or will we continue to be limited by native desktop solutions like Fiddler?

Comment: no, flash doesn't communicate with anything  that JS can intercept, unless you get into node.js and build a new server for the game, or maybe a proxy for it, but either way, you can't do it with browser-based JS...

Comment: What's the game, out of curiosity?

Comment: Hannah and the Pirate Caves. Neopets kids game that I used to enjoy playing in my early teens. Don't play it any more, but now want to develop tools for other younger players to use to build levels for it. The need to use Fiddler is preventing people from building levels, so I was hoping to integrate an automated uploading system into my level editor. It definitely seems it isn't possible purely in the browser, so I'll be investigating the suggestions on here to write a proxy server.

Comment: You might want to more clearly lay out your question. The primary way that folks edit traffic in Fiddler is by using its JavaScript engine...

Answer (score 1):

Web based proxies are totally a thing. In the same manner that your current solution uses Fiddler as an intermediary between your web browser and the game server, a website can be act as an intermediary between your browser and another website by simply making HTTP requests itself and then sending the modified results to the user.

To diagram:

Browser -> Fiddler -> WebPage (Game) -> Fiddler -> Browser

...is roughly equivalent to...

Browser -> WebPage (Proxy Server) -> WebPage (Game) -> WebPage (Proxy Server)-> Browser

And you could in theory write your proxy server entirely in javascript (see: [full stack javascript](http://www.toptal.com/javascript/guide-to-full-stack-javascript-initjs))!

But based on the fact that you ask about **javascript** specifically, I'm going to guess that you are not interested in your proxy page having a meaningful back end. This may be a problem. If you would like your proxy website to be entirely client side javascript, your diagram suddenly looks more like this:

Browser -> WebPage (Proxy Server) -> **Browser** -> WebPage (Game) -> **Browser** -> WebPage (Proxy Server)-> Browser

This is a problem because web browsers take steps to prevent this behavior by default (see: Same Origin Policy [SO won't let me put more than 2 links in this answer. You're going to have to Google this one.]). Most client-side javascript proxy solutions I can imagine violate Same Origin Policy to a significant degree (if you have control of the site serving the game you could look into CORS headers or jsonp requests - but it doesn't sound like this is an option).

If you **can** engineer a solution that doesn't violate same-origin policy you may be successful with an entirely client-side solution. In this case, I would recommend looking into async calls as a starting point (see: [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)).

Comment: I don't have control of the site serving the game, correct. So I couldn't use CORS headers. However, Javascript is not a strict requirement. I would prefer all the processing to be done client-side due to lack of server-side programming experience. But I'm willing to be flexible about this and try to write a proxy server. With the JS requirement removed, do you have any further advice? If not, you've certainly set me off in the right direction and given me hope that I can pull this off.

Comment: Also, how would I redirect the browser's HTTP requests to my proxy server? I don't have control of the creation of the HTTP request by the Flash game.

Comment: So rather than having your browser reach out the the game server directly, you would insert your proxy into the middle by having your browser contact the proxy server and then having the proxy server contact the game server.
Browser -> Proxy -> Game Server
The proxy then takes the response from the Game Server and hands it to your Browser.
Game Server -> Proxy -> Browser
In this manner, you've created a full HTTP request&response with the server that doesn't violate same origin policy (because your browser isn't actually talking to the Game Server - it's talking with the proxy).

Comment: I haven't tried this out on my own. But this might be a good jumping off point: [link](http://www.catonmat.net/http-proxy-in-nodejs/). This looks to be a simple proxy written in nodejs (server side javasscript). The author then goes on to show how to log the requests coming through the proxy. This would be your hook to do your content modifications.

Comment: Yes, the proxy server seems quite simple, especially in Node.js. However, I still don't know how I redirect the HTTP traffic going through the browser to the proxy server. I am not in control of the HTTP requests being produced by the Flash game - the game would just be embedded on the page. How do I use client-side code in my user's browser to redirect the HTTP traffic to my proxy? Surely this would violate their browser security? In other words, how do I "have the browser contact the proxy server" when the code producing the HTTP requests is inaccessible to me?